# Play framework in Scala, scope of @

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Scala and play novice here, what's the scope of `@`?

```
<ul>
  @list.map( x => {
    <li> {x.name} </li>
  })
</ul>
```

Gives me the list of names,

```
<ul>
  @list.map( x => {
    <li> x.name </li>
  })
</ul>
```

Gives me the "x.name" string repeated in a list.

```
<ul>
  @list.map( x => {
    <li> @x.name </li>
  })
</ul>
```

Gives me @x.name string repeated in a list.

So it tells me that x.name isn't considered an expression, but when I use @ to make it a Scala expression, the @ is dumped as is, and the expression doesn't compute. 
Could someone please point me to docs on the scope of @?

Thanks.

Comment: word of advice: it's much cleaner to write `@list.map{ x => <li> x.name </li> }` than it is to write `@list.map( x => { <li> x.name </li> })`, both of these work on multiple lines, but the first one saves you a set of parentheses

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates):
the end of the dynamic statement will be inferred from your code

An example:

```
Hello @customer.name!
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       Dynamic code
```

So everything between `ul` tags in your samples is parsed as scala code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain the need for using {} around x.name. If everything would be scala then x.name would have been sufficient.

Comment: These brackets are in fact part of Scala's own syntax for handling XML natively and have nothing to do with Play itself. Please see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/XML